# Proving "if $A \times B \subset B \times C$, then $A \subset C$, where $B \neq \emptyset$".

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cross-product

In short, the task was to prove the statement:

> If $A \times B \subset B \times C$, then $A \subset C$, with the constraint $B \neq \emptyset$.

**Attempted proof**:

First of all, if $A = \emptyset$, then $A \times B = \emptyset$. As the empty set is a subset of any set, both parts of the implication are true.

If $A \neq \emptyset$, we can consider any $(x,y) \in A \times B$. If $A \times B \subset B \times C$, then $(x,y) \in B \times C$ as well.

From this we see that $x \in A \land x \in B$, so per the definition of subsets $A \subset B$. We can also see that $y \in B \land y \in C$, so similarly $B \subset C$.

By the transitive property of subsets, if $A \subset B$ and $B \subset C$, then $A \subset C$.

---

However, the above proof was dismissed, so I'm curious as to what the correct approach would be, and what faulty assumptions the proof above makes?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only issue is that, since $B\ne\emptyset$, pick a $y_{0}\in B$, and start arguing that if $x\in A$, then $(x,y_{0})\in A\times B$... then you are going to have $x\in C$ at the end.

The reason for being dismissed, as I guess, is that you have written $(x,y)\in A\times B$ at the very beginning, one may ask, what if $B=\emptyset$, is that meaningful to write $(x,y)\in A\times B$ at start.

And one point further, if $A=\emptyset$, then $A=\emptyset\subseteq C$ is trivially true, no need to deal with the cross product.

Comment: I agree on the triviality of $A = \emptyset \subset C$. Could you clarify what you mean with "what if $B = \emptyset$"? The statement to prove declares that $B \neq \emptyset$, so I don't see why the scenario needs to be considered.

Comment: That is a hypothetical statement, because in your argument you didn't reveal the assumption that $B\ne\emptyset$, so it might be the case that your instructor put a question like, what if $B=\emptyset$? Of course if you receive the turn back assignment, you will quickly run and tell your instructor that but here's already the assumption in question! However, your instructor might say, but you didn't state it.

Comment: Ah, right, maybe I should've been more explicit in the phrasing above. But no, in the assignment it is already assumed that $B \neq \emptyset$, and there are no further questions assuming the contrary.

Comment: So I think your proof is okay, that's simply my guess, perhaps you should ask your instructor what's really going on with the dismiss.

Comment: Alright, I'll bring it up with the instructor again. Thanks for the assistance!